# How to prevent android app from receiving push notifications from GCM on reinstall , until user authenticates with my web service

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented an application to receive push notification from GCM,but when user reinstall's app,GCM sends notification based on old reg id which is sent to GCM from web service . How can I prevent these notifications until user authenticates with web service from the app.

I store my reg id & user mobile for each user in SharedPreferences,which get's reset when app is reinstalled but I'm not able to update this regID since the web service needs a mobile number to edit the database.

My web service is implemented in php

Comment: when a user uninstalls the app and reinstalls, their ID changes  so if you do send one to the old ID they wont get it

Comment: No GCM tries to Send notification based on canonical id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I understand your problem 
See there are two solutions to it

1. When you are registering for GCM you need to send a ProjectId which you create on Google Account in order to identify Device 
   My advice is that you guys should save IMEI number of the device and whenever you restart the app send that IMEI number back to ur backend and then delete that entry is user is not logged in.
2. Keep a polling interval within your app which pings back all the logged in User and set a timeout interval and logout users who cross the timeout period important only ping logged in users so ppl not logged in their registration id gets cleared.

Comment: Using IMEI number isn't possible because , the users can change their mobile phone & in that case they'll be locked out of our web service

Comment: @SudeshGutta Dude come on Go Read the documentation the ProjectID you create has a reference of your Device ID that is how Google detects where to push notification so if you change device do you think your user will receive Notifications until he reregisters , Dude get your concepts clear ASAP , Your User will never get notifications until you register or reregister his new device with google

Comment: Thanks for the help ... It's my first time working with Push notifications & GCM

Comment: No Problem see there are couple of things don't send push notifications on non logged in devices for this keep a ttl ie time to live for your login token second whenever he logs out kill the token now in scenarios like he deleted the app and reinstalled it how do you log him out well you can do it both on front end and also on backend now pick the alive tokens and try sending notification to devices they will fail if user doesnt have app installed so that solves part one now for second if the app is installed again every time your app starts if you are logging him out on frontend send his devi

Comment: device's unique identification to your backend so that ways you can do is kill that token and registration id which you send to your server from app only if you find him logged off

Comment: Alright  ... But as per my knowledge, I have read that GCM can change registration ID'a at random when an update happens or so , how can I handle such a situation ... Like how will the app know when to re register in case the ID'a are changed

Comment: See depends as i said if after update you are logging him out then only one thing on your backend remains constant which is device ID so remove whatever registration id you have attached with that device so that way notifications won't go to that registration ID and ask User to relogin

Comment: No not that part ... GCM sometimes tends to change registration id , so at that moment how can I make my app re register

Comment: See GCM won't change it unless you update your application it will never randomly change Registration Id and if it does it will notify your server php or whatever and then your server needs to send you the changed registration id back\

Comment: If you want complete answer raise a separate question i'll answer in detail as to how to handle that and send me question link

Comment: Ok I got it ... In the older version of GCM it used to but not now , only while app upgrade if I re register device that should do

Comment: Yes but there is more to it if you want complete detail raise a new question I'll answer